# How can i extract a yuv frame from given yuv 4:2:0 file

Tags: c, yuv

I am new to this video processing.I have assigned a task of extracting a frame from a given yuv 4:2:0 file which is in QCIF format. basically I am using c program for this.

```
         HELP me in coding
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QCIF is a raw collection of pixels composed of what are called luma, cb, cr in the following array format.A luma frame is composed of 176x144 luma samples, followed by 88x72 cb samples followed by 88x72 cr samples. [Reference](http://www.edaboard.com/thread104324.html)

```
unsigned char luma[176][144];
unsigned char cb[88][72];
unsigned char cr[88][72];
```

[Here](http://www.vlsiip.com/video/) you can find code that is used to read qcif file format.

Comment: thank you . its very useful link.

Comment: @user3106319 If it is helpful you can thank me by accepting my answer and adding +1

Comment: hi chinna, i am new to this forum. can you explain it

Comment: @user3106319 what you want me to explain? about Stack Overflow?

Comment: @user3106319 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: how can i represent the yuv4:2:0 in qcif format in a single array